# how to restrict access to many folders in node.js using express module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node.js and express as the route method, my route looks like:

```
Set the website routes
app.use('/public', express.static('./public'));
app.use('/web', express.static('./web'));
```

how can I set restrict access to 'public' and 'web' folders in one method, currently I am using two line, this code

```
app.get('/public*', checkPermissions, function(req,res,next){ next(); });
app.get('/web*', checkPermissions, function(req,res,next){ next(); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `checkPermissions` function should look like this:

```
function checkPermissions(req, res, next) {
  // logic to check whether user has permissions or not.
  // example:
  if (req.user.permissions == 'admin') {
    next();
  } else {
    // redirect if user doesn't have permission.
    res.redirect('/no-permissions');
  }
}
```

If you really want to make it fit in 1 line (dependent on lodash or underscore):

```
_.(['/public*', '/web*']).each(function(route) {
  app.get(route, checkPermissions, function(req, res, next) { next(); });
});
```

Comment: my issue not in 'checkPermissions' function, i am asking how to restrict the two folders using one line instead of two

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because i have many folders in my server, some of them share the same permissions and some not, so, i would like to group the similar permissions folder in one line instead of have many repeated lines