# Restricting route to static files in Express and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am currently trying to restrict the routes to users who haven't been logged. My main issue is that even if I define a page with a get method such as:

```
 app.get('/alpha/information', isLoggedIn,
        function(req, res){
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/alpha/pages/Example.html'));
        });
```

The user can sill just edit the url to: `http://localhost:3000/alpha/pages/Example.html` and access the page. Now I have read several similar questions on SO but I cannot find the answer. Some of which I was inspired were: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910956/how-to-protect-a-public-dynamic-folder-in-nodejs),[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732813/how-to-restrict-access-to-many-folders-in-node-js-using-express-module), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362909/how-do-i-restrict-the-user-from-accessing-the-static-html-files-in-a-expressjs-n). Nonetheless I was unable to find a solution to my issue.

My current file structure is:
[FileStructureLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3lmb.jpg)

I am trying to restrict access to **Example.html, ExampleTwo.html** and **blabla.html**

I am using this code to set up the requests but I guess they might not be right:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Alpha')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/login.html'));
```

This  `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/login.html'));` specifically is used to make the default `localhost:3000/` load as `localhost:3000/login`

How can I restrict access to all the static html files without having to write a route for each of them?

middleware function:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        console.log('here is Authenticated', req.isAuthenticated())
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
```

Comment: You can add a global authentication middleware function before any other routes (even static files) that you do not want to be accessed without login.

Comment: How do you identify whether user is logged-in or not? If you know that you can use middleware before the express.static middleware.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon Look at the folder structure, that is how I adapted the login system. I just need to restrict access via routes to static html files.

Middleware function updated.

Comment: @coderJoe have a look at my answer along with complete working and tested node-cheat, also mark answer correct if it works for you.

Comment: The answer provided by Zeeshan Hassan is NOT* tailored to the specific question.

Answer (score 11):

You can restrict your express static middleware, by attaching another middleware to it.

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require( "path" );
var app = express();

function isLoggedIn( req, res, next ) {
   console.log("trying restricted file");
   next();
}

app.use( '/Alpha', isLoggedIn, express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'Alpha' ) ) );
app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'anonymous' ) ) );

app.listen( 3000 );
```

By doing this every time you call `localhost:3000/restricted/*` will via isLoggedIn function.

EDIT: Code modified, according to your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the concept how to do it:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');
    app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Use your req.isAuthenticated logic here, that's all
    console.log('I am called before static middleware.');
    return next();
});
app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('I am called after static middleware.');
    return next();
});

app.get('/', showClientRequest, function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hi! I am direct message from server :)');
});

function showClientRequest(req, res, next) {
    console.log('You can do something here too...');
    return next();
}

app.listen(3000);
```

For complete repo:

Clone node-cheat [express_server_restrict_static_files](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/random/small_tasks/express_server_restrict_static_files), run `node app` followed by `npm install express`.

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

You are making the complete Alpha dir a public directory, thus everything is accessible. This technique is normally used to serve js/css/images.

You could make use of variable route to get the html file:

url: localhost:3000/alpha/Example

```
app.get('/alpha/:name', function(req, res) {
    var page = req.params.name;
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/alpha/pages/' + page + '.html'));
})
```

Watch for capitalisation